# Media center with offline database?

Tags: osmc

I want to use my raspberry pi 2 as movie / TV serie player. But instead of streaming content I want it to load the stuff from my USB hdd. I don't want it to download information of it but use the information from my USB hdd (so every file will be downloaden and added to the hdd manually through a PC) And then display those files in a list Like on netflix and popcorntime and when u press it you see information of the movie/episode also if possible being able to enable/disable subtitle before starting to watch.

I Have wifi on the pi and I want it to download Movies overnight wich I will place correctly on the hdd and add cover and info later with my pc.

Is there any clear tutorial for this? Havent been able to find one so far :(

Comment: Well there are many, you can try these - https://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Install_Kodi_on_Raspberry_Pi
https://beebom.com/how-install-kodi-raspberry-pi-3/
https://www.androidcentral.com/install-kodi-raspberry-pi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using raspbian check out **kodi** if you haven't already. Install it by `sudo apt-get install kodi`. And set it to autostart.

or try openELEC or OSMC from [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/)

Edit:

- Detailed instruction on installing kodi can be found [here](http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Install_Kodi_on_Raspberry_Pi) or [here](http://michael.gorven.za.net/).
- Since you already have ssh installed by default you can use [filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client) or [fireftp](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireftp/) addon for firefox to transfer files from PC.
- You can also check the quick start guide for kodi [here](http://kodi.wiki/view/Quick_start_guide)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While this technically might answer the question it would be highly beneficial to add a little more information how to tackle the question in more detail.